# set action bar item width dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am writing a custom action bar for my app. it does not show the the build in navigation icon and title. Only three buttons. At the moment one of the buttons is pushed off screen by the other two. is there a way to set the width of the menu items dynamically? in a normal xml view its a simple case of setting % size but that doesnt seem to be an option with menu items. ny help would be much appreciated. thanks.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/favourite"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/pain_guidelines_staricon"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/navButton"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@drawable/pain_guidelines_navigationbar"
            android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/actionInfo"
            android:orderInCategory="300"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@drawable/pain_guidelines_infoicon"
            android:title="Refresh"/>
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you add a screenshot here